# Dart cast using wrong type?

Tags: dart, dart-http

I'm new to Dart and was wondering over how the `.cast()` method works with dynamic types and lists.

This is a working example from the Flutter documentation on how to parse JSON manually in Dart:

```
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

where `responseBody` is some JSON array previously fetched from a HTTP endpoint.

I don't understand why the result of `json.decode(responseBody)` is cast to `Map<String, dynamic>` when logically it should be `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. I've debugged the code and in fact the variable `parsed` is a list subtype.

What am I getting wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Link to original documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is correct. `cast` is a method of `Iterable`. The type in angle brackets is the type of each element in the iterable.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/cast.html

Comment: ah, my bad. Didn't know that there are `.cast()` implementations per class.